# Compare maps with char array as values - Java

Tags: java, hashmap, arrays

I'm playing around with hashmaps right now. I'm trying to figure out how to compare the values of two hashmaps - when the values of each hashmap is a char array. I've looked around found a couple of methods that might work -I'm just not sure how to implement properly. Basically I have two maps with different keys but the same value. I want to iterate thru one of the maps and create a boolean value that returns true if they have the same value. If someone could help me figure this out, that would be great. My code is below with what I've tried thus far:

```
publipublic class MapExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, char[]> map1 = new HashMap<String, char[]>();
    Map<String, char[]> map2 = new HashMap<String, char[]>();

    char[] letters1 = new char[3];
    letters1[0] = 'a';
    letters1[1] = 'b';
    letters1[2] = 'c';

    char[] letters2 = new char[3];
    letters2[0] = 'x';
    letters2[1] = 'y';
    letters2[2] = 'z';

    map1.put("1", letters1);
    map1.put("2", letters2);
    map1.put("3", letters1);

    map2.put("4", letters1);

    Set s = map1.entrySet();
    Iterator it = s.iterator();

    boolean containsValue;

    //I've tried this but it produces false (and infinite loop) when maps have the same value
    while (it.hasNext()) {

        containsValue = map1.equals(map2.values());
        System.out.println(containsValue);
    }

    //I've tried this too, but can't seem to adjust the lists to accept char[]
    /*
    List<String> values1 = new ArrayList<String>(map1.values());
    List<String> values2 = new ArrayList<String>(map2.values());
    Collections.sort(values1);
    Collections.sort(values2);
    boolean mapsHaveEqualValues = values1.equals(values2);*/

}
 }
```

Comment: Your infinite loop is because you're not advancing the iterator. You need to call `it.next()` at some point.

Answer (score 1):

*infinite loop*

You need to use `it.next()` to advance the `Iterator`. You keep calling `hasNext()` on the iterator without forwarding it to the next element.

[hasNext()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext%28%29):

> Returns true if the iteration has more elements. (In other words, returns true if next() would return an element rather than throwing an exception.)

[next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29):

> Returns the next element in the iteration.

```
while (it.hasNext()) { 
    // need to use it.next() somewhere, but you don't really need loop here
    containsValue = map1.equals(map2.values());
    System.out.println(containsValue);
}
```

*`map1.equals(map2.values());`*

I think what you wanted to do is `map1.values().equals(map2.values());`

*`List<String> values1 = new ArrayList<String>(map1.values());`*

Define a `Character[]` instead of `char[]` and add that to the `Map<String, Character[]> map1` and the List `List<Character[]> values1 = new ArrayList<Character[]>(map1.values());`

Comment: Thanks, I should have know that one.

Comment: And the equals will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

```
containsValue = map1.equals(map2.values());
```

should be:

```
containsValue = map1.values().equals(map2.values());
```

`while(it.hasNext())` is useless in your code and you didn't use the iterator inside the loop. Regarding defining a list of `char[]`, use:

```
List<char[]> list;
```

Comment: I changed up containsValue but still have a question: Can you give me an example on adding to List<char[]> list?

Comment: The `Collection` returned from `Map.value` is, er, odd. Doesn't (necessarily) override `Object.equals`.

Answer (score 0):

Where to start with all the things that are wrong.

Calling `Object.equals` on a `char[]` will only return `true` if they are exactly the same object irrespective of contents. I note you're not relying upon that.

You are using an iterator, but never calling `next`. Best to use a posh for loop.

You are comparing a `Map` with a `Collection` (`Map` is not (usually) a `Collection`), so that isn't going to work.

The `Collection` from `Map.values` is a bag, only there is no `java.util.Bag`. Hence it happens to use the default `Object.equals`, and wont even compare equal to a collection with the same elements returned from another `Map.values` (unless it is exactly the same instance).

If you are attempting to compare the two `values` collections then we have an issue. We could easily see the common elements by copying one collection to a `HashSet` and then calling `retainAll`. To do a bag comparison you're easily going to have to use a third-party library (Guava probably, not used it myself) or implement the algorithm yourself. Say, copy to `Lists`, sort and iterate through both at once with two iterators.